# pager style in skin gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp-classic

hi i am trying to make a skin for gridview contain a css files

every thing work fine but the pager number style on hover didn't change the color of the font 
i dont know why

skin code :

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" Width="95%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  SkinId="GridBlue" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="10" Font-Names="Arial" BorderWidth="2px" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" 
     AllowSorting="true">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#faf6e0" Height="30px" CssClass="gv_hd" />
        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#faf6e0" Height="30px" CssClass="gv_ft" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#faf6e0" CssClass="gv_row" Height="30px" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ede0b9" CssClass="gv_row" Height="30px"/>

        <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" />
        <PagerStyle  Height="35px" CssClass="gv_pgr" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

        <EditRowStyle  BackColor="#dfc987" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="gv_slct" ForeColor="#5f5f5f" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#dfc987" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" font-bold="true" CssClass="gv_slct" ForeColor="#5f5f5f" />

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <center><h1 class="gv_mpty">No Records Found</h1></center>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>


    </asp:GridView>
```

css code :

```
.gv{text-align:center;}
.gv_hd{height:22px;text-decoration:none;border:#5f5f5f solid 2px;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #548975), color-stop(1, #37705a));background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);}
.gv_hd a{text-decoration:none;}
.gv_hd a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
.gv_hd a:active{text-decoration:underline;}
.gv_ft{padding:10px;text-decoration:none;border:#5f5f5f solid 2px;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #548975), color-stop(1, #37705a));background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #548975 5%, #37705a 100%);}
.gv_row{text-align:center;color:#5f5f5f;padding:}
.gv_row a{text-decoration:none;}
.gv_row a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
.gv_pgr{color:#5f5f5f;padding:20px;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #faf6e0), color-stop(1, #e7d6a1));background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #faf6e0 5%, #e7d6a1 100%);background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #faf6e0 5%, #e7d6a1 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #faf6e0 5%, #e7d6a1 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #faf6e0 5%, #e7d6a1 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #faf6e0 5%, #e7d6a1 100%);}
.gv_pgr a{font-weight:bold;margin-top:10px;background-color:transparent;padding:4px 10px;text-decoration:none;border:1px solid #d9c074;}
.gv_pgr a:hover{font-weight:bold;background-color:#548975;border:1px solid #d9c074;color:White;}
.gv_pgr a:active{font-weight:bold;background-color:#548975;color:#faf6e0;border:1px solid #d9c074;}
.gv_pgr span{background-color:#548975;color:#faf6e0;border:1px solid #d9c074;padding:4px 10px;}
.gv_mpty{color:#5f5f5f;}
.gv_slct a{text-decoration:none;text-align:center;}
.gv_slct a:hover{text-decoration:underline;text-align:center;}
```

on hover the font of the pager didn't change

Comment: This is not Classic ASP, please retag.

Answer (score 0):

when the grid is rendered, you can use F12 to check the CSS, html. Make sure that the row as the class you want to make the highlight work.

Comment: everything seems ok, that's why i asked you to inspect the html. Are you sure the pager contain link ? Probably the selector is the problem. Make sure nothing is in cache in the browser, hit ctrl+r to clear the cache and reload the css.

Comment: ok i found the solution : 
on the hover css : color:#..... !important;
its solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
.gv_pgr a:hover{font-weight:bold;background-color:#548975;border:1px solid #d9c074;color:White !Improtant;}
```

by adding !important to the color code